# Problems interpreting ar file within code

Tags: c++

I've been trying to interpret an ar(the libglib-2.0.a) file using this [struct](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/refs/heads/jb-dev/sysroot/usr/include/ar.h) here declared in `ar.h`. Acording to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)) the ending characters shoud be 0x60 and 0x0A, but what I got is  0x35 and 0x34, in fact the ending characters are actually 8 bytes ahead in the stream!
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <elf.h>
#include <ar.h>


int main(){
    int fd = open("libglib-2.0.a", O_RDONLY);

    char b[1000];

    read(fd, b, 1000);

    ar_hdr *arS = (ar_hdr*) b;

    int dummy = 0;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Both ways give me the same result

Comment: Why did you use 1000? This doesn't make sense, let alone strict aliasing rules.

Comment: The whole file is 2mb, I didn't want to open all of it in one go. I just wanted to check the ar header file. Does that modify the bytes at all?

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you determine the end characters of the header.  And what's `dummy` for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you miss the 8 bytes offset at the top.

```
#define ARMAG   "!<arch>\n" /* String that begins an archive file.  */
#define SARMAG  8       /* Size of that string.  */
```

Then, you create a buffer of a bizarre size — 1000. That value makes absolutely no sense, we have a correct buffer size for it, which is the size of header itself — we know it statically, it's 60 bytes. Not to mention that to interpret the buffer as a correct struct, memory representation should be properly aligned.

Here's a working example, for the sake of brevity, error-checking is omitted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "unistd.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ar.h"

int main() {
    int fd = open("/usr/lib/libc.a", O_RDONLY);

    lseek(fd, SARMAG, SEEK_SET);

    ssize_t bufSize = sizeof(struct ar_hdr);
    char buf[bufSize];
    read(fd, buf, bufSize);

    struct ar_hdr header;
    memcpy(&header, buf, bufSize);

    printf("\%02hhx, \%02hhx\n", header.ar_fmag[0], header.ar_fmag[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ ./read
60, 0a
```

Comment: So with the header having been read, how to procede reading the rest of the file? How to get the objects data out of it?

Comment: For example, https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/3head/ar.h/ it says that there is a symbol table, but I couldn't understand how to get there. Is the symbol table right after the ar header?

Comment: I don't think that was the original submission, correct me if I am wrong. This looks like two different problems to me.

Comment: Yes, they really are. I should ask another question.